# Is there a way I can use Ubuntu as a proxy server, including me the chance to create temporary users and passwords?

Tags: proxy

I would like to ask... I´m working in the network maintenance of some high schools here in my city, and one of the principals asked me if there is a chance to create some free access points for the students, with some restrictions also, some are that they cannot access social networks, youtube and restricted or porn pages, and also if there´s a possibility to provide these accesses with temporary users and passwords... the first part is simple, but for the second one I´m not sure what to do... I know, for example, that the Fortinet switches and routers have this option, they can create generic users and passwords for maybe three hours or so, but I´m not sure if this is possible with free software... A fortinet switch is up to $3000 depending the place where you get it, and for the budget´s high school it is too difficult to get it.... So, I was wondering if you guys can advice me if there is something into the Ubuntu´s world I can use to do that, I do really appreciate the help you can provide me... 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for you to do this by running Squid on Ubuntu Server.

Of course you should read much about.

Here are some interesting links:

http://www.deckle.co.uk/squid-users-guide/index.html.

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Authentication

Squid is a very fast proxy-cache program.

But what is a proxy cache?

Proxy:  An agent that has authority to act for another.

Cache: A hiding place for concealing and preserving provisions which it is inconvenient to carry.

Squid acts as an agent, accepting requests from clients (such as browsers) and passes them to the appropriate Internet server. It stores a copy of the returned data in an on-disk cache.